# Simple phone regex

Tags: regex, phone-number

I want a regex that checks the following things:

1. The string starts with an +
2. After the '+' only numbers can occur
3. There should be atleast 4 numbers after the +

Does anyone know how to make this?

Comment: is there any limit for numbers?? i.e. atleast 4 and atmost??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/^+\d{4,}$/
```

will meet your requirements.

`^` is the anchor for start fo the string

`\d` is a digit

`{4,}` says at least 4 of the preceding expression (here the `\d`). you can add a maximum if needed like `{4,20}` would allow at least 4 and at most 20 characters.

`$` is the anchor for the end of the string

Comment: Awesome thanks. I haver understand a bit about regular expressions :)

Answer (score 1):

```
/^((00|\+)[0-9]{2,3}){0,1}[0-9]{4,14}$/
```

More general than your request, but you can specialize it. Explaining:

```
((00|\+)[0-9]{2,3})
```

international code with 00 or + and 2 or 3 digits. Modify the expression according to your needs.

```
 {0,1}
```

international code is optional - remove it if it is required

```
[0-9]{4,14}
```

digits: minimum 4, maximum 14. Change the values according to your needs.

Regards
A.

Answer (score 1):

```
/\+\d{4,15}/
```

This should help if 15 is the atmost limit of numbers

OR rather keep the second parameter blank as stema suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I went with this one:

```
/\A(([+]\d{3,})?\d{6,8})/
```